# TD expand to size of absolutely positioned content

Tags: html, css, html-table, position

I have a table which contains 3 td. The first td has a relative positioned div which contains 2 absolutely positioned divs. I wish that the first td take the width of his content, so he doesn't overlap over the next td. How i can achieve this?

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-test-id="parent" style="inset: 0px;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <div data-test-id="YAxisTd" style="position: relative;">
      <div class="flot-text" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px; font-size: smaller;">
        <div class="flot-y-axis flot-y1-axis yAxis y1Axis" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px;">
         <div class="flot-tick-label tickLabel" data-test-id="**ticks**" style="position: absolute; top: 722px; left: 21px; text-align: right;">
            100000%
         </div>
         <div class="flot-tick-label tickLabel" data-test-id="**ticks**" style="position: absolute; top: 626px; left: 21px; text-align: right;">
            300000%
         </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="axisLabels yaxisLabel" style="top: 0; left: 0;-webkit-transform: translate(-5.47655px, 362.5px) rotate(-90deg);">
      </div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to change the absolute position of flot-text/flot-y-axis/flot-tick-label as I did for axisLabels but after all the **ticks** becomes randomly positioned. The top/left are calculated by FLOT library.

Comment: Hi, why are you positioning the inner divs in the first td absolutely if you want their width to be taken into account?

Comment: Hello, the inner divs are a label and some ticks, which together define a vertical axis. I need to be absolutely positioned so they can be aligned to the chart.